# How to apply changes in QSettings immediately?

Tags: pyqgis, table-of-contents, macro

With PyQGIS, you can change various settings such as making the groups in the Layers Panel (or table of contents) bold:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/legendGroupsBold", True)
```

The settings are written which can be seen from the options or from typing:

```
QSettings().value("/Qgis/legendGroupsBold")
>>> u'true'
```

But it does not get applied. I thought using

```
QSettings().sync()
```

might help but unfortunately not. The only way for it to apply would be to either go to the GUI (`Settings > Options`) then click <kbd>OK</kbd> or restart QGIS.

Is there a method to doing this through PyQGIS?

---

**Context**:

I want to add this as a macro in a project file to ensure (for aesthetic purposes) that only group names are bold and layer names are not. Therefore, it would be ideal if the QSettings are applied when the project has loaded (the initial settings would be reapplied when the project closed).

Comment: When you call sync() to commit your changes, do you then call status()?

Comment: @whyzar - Thanks but tested that too and still no change.

Comment: It's so strange,maybe a bug because occurs the same using `QSettings().setValue("/qgis/legendLayersBold", False)` .I think that the issue is in this line https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/src/app/qgsoptions.cpp#L1458

Comment: the possible method is `QgisApp::instance()->legend()->updateLegendItemStyles();` but in a future version probably?

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - Thanks for the link, it does seem like a bug. I was thinking of posting a bug report but with QGIS 3.0 coming out soon, I'll wait and see if this problem still exists in the new version =)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible unless you write a **key** with the default state into your `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\qgis\UI\state` [take a look here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html).

actually, when we restart the software it automatically does this for us.

check this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings( "QGIS", "QGIS2" ).remove( "/UI/state" )
QSettings( "QGIS", "QGIS2" ).remove( "/ComposerUI/state" )


#(for 1.8 it's QGIS instead of QGIS2 IIRC).
```

if it does not work, you have to write a script to rewrite that registry value.

to do so you need to use **winreg** to manipulate registry values.

you can view your registry keys via [regedit.exe](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/where-are-the-windows-registry-files-located-in-windows-7) if you use windows.

I hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I would still have to restart QGIS when the key is written by the macro for QGIS to read it during startup. Still trying to find a way :)